# Use Chrome's Element Inspector to track where an event listener was added

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find the code where an event listener was added to an element. Chrome's Element Inspector helps in showing which events were added, I'd like to find the code in which it was added and disable it.

[image]

Is there a way to jump to the location in source code where the atachement of event was made?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to jump to the location in source code?

You **can** (click the underlined `jquery.min.js` to the right of the word `document`). The problem is, it wouldn't help you much, because it would take you to jQuery's central event handler for that event for the element, not the specific handler you want to find. jQuery only hooks a given event on an element once; if there are multiple handlers attached with jQuery, it manages them itself (so it can ensure order and a few other things on older browsers).

It would be laborious, but you could override `on` (which `bind` and various other things end up calling anyway) and set a breakpoint in your overridden version (filtering for the event you're interested in, and optionally the element). Then run your page and look at the caller each time the breakpoint is hit.

Here's how you'd do a basic override of `on` (immediately after loading jQuery):

```
var original = jQuery.fn.on;
jQuery.fn.on = function() {
    /*...your logic here...*/
    return original.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

...or alternately set a breakpoint within your `jquery.js` file (don't try to use the minified version).

It may be slightly easier to override the internal `jQuery.event.add` function instead, because all of the `on` pre-processing has been done by that point:

```
var original = jQuery.fn.on;
jQuery.event.add = function(elem, types) {
    if ((elem matches the one you care about) &&
        /\bclick\b/i.test(types)) {
        debugger;
    }
    return original.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

So for instance, if you only care about `click` added to an element with `id="foo"`, then:

```
var original = jQuery.fn.on;
jQuery.event.add = function(elem, types) {
    if (elem.id === "foo" &&          // `elem` is a DOM element, not a jQuery object
        /\bclick\b/i.test(types)) {
        debugger;
    }
    return original.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, code is very clear, I just don't understand where is 'immediately after loading jQuery'

Comment: @Keren: In a script block just after `<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>`